# Ошибка "не все пути к коду возвращают значение"

Tags: c#

Задание - написать метод, принимающий int значение number и возвращающий сумму чисел от 1 до number.
Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем причина ошибки "CS0161 - "Program.Sum(int)": Не все пути к коду возвращают значение" и как этой ошибки избежать.

```
class Program
    {
        static int Sum(int number)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                result += i;
                return result;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(Sum(number));

        }
    }
```

Comment: а зачем вы в цикле возвращаете результат?

Comment: `return result;` должно быть за пределами цикла

Comment: `в чем причина` - ну, в ошибке вам прямым текстом говорят, в чем `Не все пути возвращают значение`. Задайте себе вопрос, а что вернет метод, если условия цикла не сработает, к примеру, если вызвать `Sum(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Не все пути к коду возвращают значение` - значит, что есть такие параметры, при которых функция, которая должна вернуть значение, выполнит команду return - то есть не вернет значение. Это может произойти по разным случаям: вы не написали команду return, вы написали ее в условии, которое не всегда истинно, ИЛИ вы написали ее в цикле, который может не дойти до этой строки.

Проще говоря, представьте, что произойдет, если на вход в функцию попадет неположительное число.

Если вы хотите посчитать сумму чисел от 1 до N, то возвращение результата должно будет после цикла, когда результат переменной result сформировался окончательно:

```
static int Sum(int number)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                result += i;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
class Program
    {
        static int Sum(int number)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                result += i;
            }
            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(Sum(number));

        }
    }
```

Значение нужно возвращать вне цикла