# Ошбика not all code paths return a value в коде

Tags: c#

Написал код, который должен сравнить цену при вводе пользователем с ценой в 10000, если цена больше либо равна 10000 то должна выводиться сумма с учетом скидки. Если цена меньше то она и должна выводиться.

Скажите где ошибка?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int totalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Discount(totalPrice);
}

static int Discount(int Price)
{
    if(Price >= 10000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(0.2 * Price);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Price);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка у вас в непонимание языка. Почитайте про методы, увидите, что если пишете `тип Название() { ... }`, то этот метод должен что-то вернуть, а у вас просто вывод в консоль...

Comment: "Ошбика **all** code paths **do not** return a value в коде"

Comment: Да я не особо понимаю конкретно методы еще, может поможете с кодом?

Comment: Тут всё описано https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values

Comment: вместо `static int Discount(int Price)` напишите `static void Discount(int Price)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка "не все пути к коду возвращают значение"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1191476/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int totalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Discount(totalPrice);
}

static void Discount(int Price)
{
    if(Price >= 10000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(0.2 * Price);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Price);
    }
}
```

Метод имеющий [тип возвращаемого значения int] обязательно должен вернуть целое число. У вас он ничего не возвращает. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.8.php